# recover file saved by hitting Ctrl + S on Visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2010

I've complied some code today using Visual studio. I kept hitting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd> meanwhile coding but I have never "Saved as...". Eventually Visual Studio crashed and my code is lost ='(
Will it be possible to recover it?

Answer (score 0):

Check under C:\Users\[username]\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects

Comment: the folder is empty ='(

Comment: Make sure it's saving your projects there. Unless you deleted it yourself, there's no reason VS crashing would delete a folder. You're sure you were saving it as you went?